# Serialize Linq to SQL result into JSON (newtonsoft) in C# or VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, linq-to-sql

I have a plain and simple Linq to SQL query:

```
dim result = from c in ctx.customers select c
```

How can I use Newtonsoft.JSON to serialize the result using VB.NET (preferably) or c#?

As I'm lazy as a programmer, I don't want to create a class for the result because there will be many different queries (yes, downvote me... Make my day :-)

Comment: "Write my code for me" -OP
What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm)

`dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)`

Comment: Simple, soooo simple when you know the answer! Thanks for prompt response :-)